# decrease algorithm time on python program calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, real-time, python-3.7

i have  **algorithm on python** that calculate a **filters** (low_pass,high_pass...) ,  in my program I'm reading data from real time device  and i  need to process it,  and  transmit it back to device.
each chunks of data comes every 10 millisecond, so in this time i must calculate as many filter as i can.
**my algorithm** :

```
def do_calculation(self,indata,outdata):
  for i in range(0,len(indata)):
    val=self.a0*indata[i]
    val+=self.a1*self.xn1 
    val+=self.a2*self.xn2 
    val-=self.b1*self.yn1 
    val-=self.b2*self.yn2
    outdata[i]= val
    self.xn2 = self.xn1
    self.xn1 = indata[i]
    self.yn2 = self.yn1
    self.yn1 = outdata[i]
```

the coefficient(a0,a1,a2,b1,b2) i calculate before i start the read/write.

i call this function from the Main function  with every input that i get from device , process it , and write it back to device by using outdata.
**indata is list in size of 512 like this**
list[[x0,x1][x1,x2].....[x510,x511]]

there is any way that i can **improve performance of this function**? or maybe python is very limitation  about it.
for now, each filter take something like **2 or 3**(there is some filter that take even 5) millisecond and i want to decrease it so i can create more filter in this range of 10 millisecond.

thanks for help!

Comment: Well depending on the datatype of indata, you could iterate directly on that : ```for i in indata :``` if it's a numpy.darray it'll be faster, otherwise if it's a list, you can convert it into a numpy.darray and do just that

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm? The code looks like you are just applying a sliding window (``xn1``, ``xn2`` being ``indata[i-1:i+1]`` and likewise for ``y``) but the purpose of storing data on ``self`` is unclear.  Does this get called repeatedly on new ``indata``? Can the same object handle several ``indata`` at once, or is there a well-defined sequence of ``indata``s? Do ``self.a1``, ``self.a2``, ``self.b1``, ``self.b2`` change during or between calls of ``do_calculation``?

Comment: i do some calculation on variable call **val**  with  some coefficient that i define when i init the filter object(lowpass,highpass...)  on each iterate i need to save the the previous
 calculation and to use it in the next one.. I the end outdata will be the expected filter. (a0,a1,a2,b1,b2 )will remain the same during the all calculation.

Comment: A simple improvement would be to load ``a0``, ... and ``xn1`` to local variables, and do read/write to ``self`` attributes only before and after the loop. Depending on how slow your code currently is (please clarify in your question) and how fast it should be (please clarify in your question) that won't be enough, though. Depending on how large each ``indata``/``outdata`` slice is (please clarify in your question) using ``numpy`` for vectorised operations might be beneficial or detrimental. It could be that you need a compiler, e.g. PyPy's JIT, Cython's AOT or a fully compiled language.

Comment: OK, i thought about insert only this calculation to c program and combine it into python..  its possible to do that ?

Comment: Typical values of the constants? - Are they all floats? less than 1? Negative? Integers? This greatly affects timings.

Comment: yes , they all float and less  than 1 , and there is a lot of  negative numbers. there is something that i can do with this to decrease the calculation time ?

Comment: Please clearly define what the current performance is, and order of magnitude a desirable improvement is. There are many somethings to decrease the calculation time, but it is unclear whether these would be sufficient for you. There are also a few somethings to *significantly* decrease the calculation time, but it is unclear whether explaining these would be worthwhile.

Comment: in a lot of cases my xn1 or xn2 will be zero so in that the next iteration that  involves this value wiil by Unnecessary but in some cases the value is not zero , i want to avoid the cases that i do calculation when the value of xn1 or xn2 is zero but when in do it with if statement is increase the time calculation

Comment: my performance  for now is that the whole calculation of filter takes 1,2 millisecond , and i want to decrease it less than 1 millisecond ,   like i said in my previous,comment i have a lot an Unnecessary calculation and im trying to find a way to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third version `do_calculation3` below is twice as fast as your version

```
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a0 = .1
        self.a1 = .02
        self.a2 = -.3
        self.b1 = .2
        self.b2 = -.25
        self.xn1 = -.1
        self.xn2 = .11
        self.yn1 = .12
        self.yn2 = -.001
        self.ab = [self.a0, self.a1, self.a2, -self.b1, -self.b2]
        self.xy = [self.xn1, self.xn2, self.yn1, self.yn2]

    def do_calculation(self,indata,outdata):
      for i in range(0,len(indata)):
        val=self.a0*indata[i]
        val+=self.a1*self.xn1 
        val+=self.a2*self.xn2 
        val-=self.b1*self.yn1 
        val-=self.b2*self.yn2
        outdata[i]= val
        self.xn2 = self.xn1
        self.xn1 = indata[i]
        self.yn2 = self.yn1
        self.yn1 = outdata[i]

    def do_calculation2(self,indata,outdata):
        xy = self.xy
        ab = self.ab
        for i, ini in enumerate(indata):
            val = sum((n * m for n, m in zip(ab, [ini] + xy)))
            outdata[i] = val
            xy = [ini, xy[0], val, xy[2]]
        self.xy = xy

    def do_calculation3(self,indata,outdata):
        j,k,l,m,n = self.ab
        xn1, xn2, yn1, yn2 = self.xn1, self.xn2, self.yn1, self.yn2
        for i, ini in enumerate(indata):
            outdata[i] = val = j*ini + k*xn1 + l*xn2 + m*yn1 + n*yn2
            xn1, xn2, yn1, yn2 = ini, xn1, val, yn1
        self.xn1, self.xn2, self.yn1, self.yn2 = xn1, xn2, yn1, yn2


c = C()
dati = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato = [0 for _ in dati]
c.do_calculation(dati, dato)

c2 = C()
dati2 = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato2 = [0 for _ in dati2]
c2.do_calculation2(dati2, dato2)

c3 = C()
dati3 = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato3 = [0 for _ in dati3]
c3.do_calculation3(dati3, dato3)

assert dato == dato2
assert dato == dato3

#%%
print('\n## do_calculation\n')
c = C()
dati = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato = [0 for _ in dati]
%timeit c.do_calculation(dati, dato)

print('\n## do_calculation2\n')
c2 = C()
dati2 = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato2 = [0 for _ in dati2]
%timeit c2.do_calculation2(dati2, dato2)

print('\n## do_calculation3\n')
c3 = C()
dati3 = list((1/x if x else 0) for x in range(512))
dato3 = [0 for _ in dati3]
%timeit c3.do_calculation3(dati3, dato3)
```

## Timings

```
## do_calculation

887 µs ± 35.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

## do_calculation2

1.49 ms ± 417 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

## do_calculation3

332 µs ± 83.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```